# Black vertical rectangle on left margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I print my document on A5 paper. I have a template with header and footer. Now, my laserjet printer is spoiling the page by leaving black marks on left margin. How can I draw a black vertical strip of 5 mm width on the left margin to hide these marks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `background` package.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newsavebox\mybox
\sbox\mybox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \fill[black] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.south west) +(5mm,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\backgroundsetup{
angle=0,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
color=black,
contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=west] at  (current page.west) {\usebox{\mybox}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
}
\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Some text\newpage

\section{Another section}
Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the extra box and the three levels of nesting `tikzpicture`s (the package already uses one)? It's enough to say `\backgroundsetup{
angle=0,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
color=black,
contents={
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[black] 
      (current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=5mm]current page.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}`; the `calc` library also isn't required.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina `box` is used with an intention to reduce load. And `xshift` is a good idea. Using `calc` has been a habit for me though :) Thanks. :)

Answer (score 7):

With the help of `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` from the `eso-pic` package, we draw a black rectangle at the shipout of every page.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[black] (current page.north west) --
                 ($(current page.north west) +(5mm,0)$) --
                 ($(current page.south west) +(5mm,0)$) --
                 (current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Some text\newpage

\section{Another section}
Some text

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Can we make the open side wavy ribbon like?

Comment: @user34083 this goes beyond my tikz knowledge... Please ask a follow-up question for this.