# Making one side of a rectangle wavy

Tags: tikz-pgf, eso-pic

Following is the MWE for putting a black rectangle on the left side of a page to hide black marks that printer leaves on every paper (? old cartridge).

How can I make the open side of the rectangle wavy or ribbon-like to make it look decorative?

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[black] (current page.north west) --
                 ($(current page.north west) +(5mm,0)$) --
                 ($(current page.south west) +(5mm,0)$) --
                 (current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Some text\newpage

\section{Another section}
Some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: note that this is a followup to this question: [black verticle rectangle on left margin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166397/579).

Comment: I've updated my answer with new information regarding the solutions using the `background` package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option using a `tape` shape from `shapes.symbols`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[
  tape,
  fill=black,
  minimum height=2cm,%\paperheight,
  minimum width=\paperheight,
  rotate=90]
 at (current page.west) 
{};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Some text\newpage

\section{Another section}
Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing `tape bend height`, you can produce something more "wavy":

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[
  tape,
  fill=black,
  minimum height=2cm,
  minimum width=\paperheight,
  tape bend height=20pt,
  rotate=90]
 at (current page.west) 
{};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Some text\newpage

\section{Another section}
Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with a `coil` decoration:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \fill[black, decorate, decoration={coil,segment length=30pt}] 
    (current page.north west) -- 
    ([xshift=8mm,yshift=5mm]current page.north west) --
    ([xshift=8mm,yshift=-5mm]current page.south west) --
    (current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Some text.
\newpage

\section{Another section}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Again, playing with the decoration attributes you can get a different effect:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \fill[black, decorate, decoration={coil,segment length=90pt,aspect=0}] 
    (current page.north west) -- 
    ([xshift=8mm,yshift=5cm]current page.north west) --
    ([xshift=8mm,yshift=-5cm]current page.south west) --
    (current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Some text.
\newpage

\section{Another section}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Mark Wibrow** has suggested in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166419/making-one-side-of-rectangle-wavy/166445?noredirect=1#comment382382_166445), if the rectangle is always going to be on the left side, speed can be improved by decorating just the right side of the rectangle; for example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \fill[black, decoration={coil,segment length=90pt,aspect=0}] 
    (current page.north west) -- 
    ([xshift=8mm,yshift=5cm]current page.north west) 
    decorate { --
    ([xshift=8mm,yshift=-5cm]current page.south west) } --
    (current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
Some text.
\newpage

\section{Another section}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

Notice that for this you don't really need the `tikznodepages` package since the nodes used are already defined by standard TikZ. Also, one can dispense with the use of the `calc` library.

### Update:

I see that in [your original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166397/3954) you decided to switch to the `background` package; in this case, all you have to do to translate my example codes above is to place the `tikzpicture` environment as the value for the `contents` key, as the following example shows (there's no need for an extra box nor another extra `tikzpicture` as in the accepted answer to the other question; the `calc` library also isn't required):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\backgroundsetup{
angle=0,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
color=black,
contents={
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[
  tape,
  fill=black,
  minimum height=2cm,%\paperheight,
  minimum width=\paperheight,
  rotate=90]
 at (current page.west) 
  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
}
\begin{document}

Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might get some marginal improvements in speed if you decorate only the right edge of the rectangle, for example `\fill [decoration=coil] (A) -- (B) decorate { -- (C) } -- (D) -- cycle;`

Comment: @MarkWibrow You're right; I'll introduce the changes. Thanks.

Comment: Actually thinking about it, it's only a good idea if the rectangle is always on the left hand side of the page. Otherwise your original solution is probably better.

Comment: @MarkWibrow Yes. In any case, I added a remark about your suggestion, in case the rectangle is always to the left.

Answer (score 6):

I used TikZ and its `decorations.pathmorphing` library. I made rectangle higher than `\paperheight` to make sure decoration is covering whole area we need.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \fill[black, decorate, decoration=snake] 
    (current page.north west) -- 
    ($(current page.north west) +(5mm,5mm)$) --
    ($(current page.south west) +(5mm,-5mm)$) --
    (current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}}% End of \AddToShipoutPictureBG
\begin{document}
\section{A section}Some text.\newpage
\section{Another section}Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]